# GIT push creates a temporary (?) "file.html~" file of my commited file? Why?

Tags: linux, git, ubuntu, github, push

it's my first using the git commands on a linux environment and I got a weird problem. I cloned a git repository and changed the file "index.html" for testing purposes. I use the following commands after that:

> $git add .
>
> $git commit - m "test"
>
> $git push

It works fine, expect that it created a second file of the index.html, named "index.html~"why?
thank you :)

/edit: The file doesnt exist in my local repository tho..

Comment: There's a missing step here, you probably editet index.html somewhere inbetween your git commands, and perhaps it's your editor that owns the index.html~

Comment: To be safe, always type git status before git add . (and possibly also git diff) so you know what will actually be added to the staging area and what will eventually get committed.

Answer (score 1):

Files with `~` are generally created you start editing the file, so I suppose you committed when your index.html was being opened/edited

Answer (score 1):

linux user? use gedit or etc editor?

create .gitignore file and add string inside this file:

```
*~
```

Comment: thank you, can you tell me where do i find the .gitignore file? I have a local repository but there is no file in it.

Answer (score 0):

`git push` does not touch your working directory, it just sends your local commits to a remote server. It is essentially a read-only operation on the local repository (just the remote-tracking refs are updated).

So `git push` can't be the one creating this `*~` file. As said elsewhere, your text editor (e.g. Emacs) probably is.

I suggest that you ignore *all* `*~` files by adding `*~` to `~/.config/git/ignore` (create the file and directories if they do not exist).